# Magento2 : How to add Upload Field in Payment Method section for checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to create my custom payment method which I created now.

And **I want to create upload file field and save in payment table in database, and also save file in folder and attach in email.**
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post what you tried, So that contributors will understand and provide solutions easily.

Comment: i have created payment method already by using this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/   and placing order all works fine now i also want add filed in upload file

Comment: HI, have you found anything on this?